# Endomorphism restricted to orthogonal of 1-subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A: V \rightarrow V$ be a skew-symmetric vector spaces endomorphism. Assume that there exists $u \in V$ such that
$$ \langle u \rangle \not\subset \text{im }A$$
By skew-symmetry of $A$, $\ker{A}$ and $\text{im A}$ are orthogonal complements, so this is equivalent to
$$
\langle{u\rangle}^{\perp} \not\supset \ker{A}
$$

**Question**: Is the restriction of $A$ to $\langle{u\rangle}^{\perp}$ contained in $\langle{u\rangle}^{\perp}$?
$$
\tag{?}
A\left(\langle{u\rangle}^{\perp}\right) \subset \langle{u\rangle}^{\perp}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample can be given by
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $u = (1,0,1)^t$.

Answer (score 0):

No, a counterexample is given by

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & -1 \\
-2 & 0 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$